# Strong reference cycle for closures in Swift

Tags: swift

I was going through the documentation (chapter on “Automatic Reference Counting” section “Strong Reference Cycles for Closures”) and I can't seem to figure out cases, when defining a class, in which I should keep a strong reference to `self` (the instance of that class) in a closure to a property.
Capture Lists seem always the best solution to avoid memory leaks, and I really can't think of any scenarios in which I should keep a strong reference cycle.

Here are the examples that the documentation gives:

```
class HTMLElement {

    let name: String
    let text: String?

    // Without Capture List 
    @lazy var asHTML: () -> String = {
        if let text = self.text {
            return "<\(self.name)>\(text)</\(self.name)>"
        } else {
            return "<\(self.name) />"
        }
    }

    init(name: String, text: String? = nil) {
        self.name = name
        self.text = text
    }

    deinit {
        println("\(name) is being deinitialized")
    }

}
```

---

```
class HTMLElement {

    let name: String
    let text: String?

    // With Capture List
    @lazy var asHTML: () -> String = {
        [unowned self] in
        if let text = self.text {
            return "<\(self.name)>\(text)</\(self.name)>"
        } else {
            return "<\(self.name) />"
        }
    }

    init(name: String, text: String? = nil) {
        self.name = name
        self.text = text
    }

    deinit {
        println("\(name) is being deinitialized")
    }

}
```

Comment: and what is your question exactly?

Comment: "I really can't think of any scenarios in which I should keep a strong reference cycle" -> are there any?

Comment: That is an example of not optimized code to be avoided.

Answer (score 6):

You need to keep a strong reference to self if you’re creating a closure to be executed by an object or function whose lifetime may not match self’s.

For example:

```
class A {
    func do() {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(0, 0)) {
            println("I printed \(self) some time in the future.")
        }
    }
}

var a : A? = A()
a.do()
a = nil // <<<
```

At the arrow the main function body will release its last reference to the newly created instance of A, but the dispatch queue needs to keep a hold on it until the closure is done executing.

Comment: Thanks for this. It makes sense to me now. Why do you think strong reference to self is the "default" behaviour, though? It doesn't seem very a memory-friendly behaviour. Thanks!

Comment: Making it a strong reference is the safest behaviour to default to, because that guarantees the object still exists when the closure is executed -- a weak reference means it could suddenly be nil, and an unowned reference means it could point to invalid data. Also, it's (arguably) more common for closures to be used as parameters to external methods (e.g. callbacks for some future outside event) than it is to store them as properties on the class that created the closure. In these cases, capturing `self` as a strong reference is often a perfectly reasonable course of action.